# After click app notification, start new activity, but unable to get data on sqlite db

Tags: android

I am working on android application, I want everytime the user click on the notification, it will start new activity, however, the activity has started, but unable to read any data from sqlite

I have splashscreen before mainactivity started. I have set to open splashscreen or mainactivity after clicking the notification, both do the same, it will through oncreate process but unable to get any data from sqlite
I have checked the db connection and it is not null

pending intent

```
Intent resultIntent;
        resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("act", "alert");
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

main activity oncreate

```
HashMap user = new HashMap();
        db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        user = db.getUser();
```

if `mainactivity` started from clicking the notification, the `user` value is always null
but if `mainactivity` started from launcher, it always return correct data

please help, why is this happen? and how to fix it? thank you

Answer (score 0):

finally after spending a day, I find the solution

actually, the problem is on the way exiting the app,

I was using `System.exit(0);` , strange behaviour happened after closing the application and reopen the app by clicking the notification dont know why

delete the code and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on the notification android open you **MainActivity** than in **onCreate()** call get the intent you passed in **PendingIntent** like below

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  if (intent != null) {
   String data = intent.getStringExtra("act");
   if (data != null) {
    getCallForDataFromSqlite();
   }
  }
```

Keep coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because when your activity is started from clicking the notification, your onCreate() won't be called, look here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html?hl=ru#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.